# How to sync Google Contacts with Outlook 365 contacts?

Tags: google-contacts, synchronization, outlook-365

Is it possible to sync Google Contacts with Outlook 365 contacts?

Comment: The instructions are described in this blog post: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/sync-gmail-and-outlook-contacts-automatically/

Comment: Tried the link above, but could not sign in to Google account.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

As @Luke the Geek pointed out in the comments, there are third-party utilities that will allow you to do this.  This may be your best option if you have an older version of Windows.

But, there is a native method in Windows 10 (and likely other Windows platforms, such as their mobile ones) for accomplishing this: use the People app.  As noted in the comments, this is not a true sync.  It is best used for maintaining them both in one location.

Essentially, you sync both Outlook and Google Contacts with People:

1. Search from your taskbar/start menu for People
2. Click on the gear on the lower-left to open Settings
3. Click Add Account, and follow the prompts to add both your Google and Outlook accounts, and set up their sync:

[image: Add Account dialog]

4. Be aware that you might need to use Exchange, not Outlook, depending on how your account is actually set up

Comment: The above solution put both contact lists in one place, but it does not update contact in one account to another.

Comment: yeah, this was a waste of time. doesn't do what OP asked for. :/

Answer (score 0):

I found this software **Outlook4Gmail**. And now I'm trying the Pro version for free, and it seems working well so far.
https://outlook4gmail.scand.com/

Free version is limited. Label and Group are ignored.

Also tried Contact Sync, but could not sign into a Google account.
http://www.pppindia.com/contacts-sync/

I had been using Thunderbird synced with Google Contacts, but the Addon I used for syncing stopped working, and I have to look for altenatives. It's remarkable why there aren't reliable builtin tools for syncing.